# creating a Public/private key for google using API call

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys) says that I can get the keys by this request:

```
POST https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT-ID/serviceAccounts/SA-NAME@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com/keys
```

I created a service account.
For the example lets say:

```
SA-NAME = xxx
PROJECT-ID = yy-zz
```

When i do (Python)

```
import requests
url = 'https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/yy-zz/serviceAccounts/xxx@yy-zz.iam.gserviceaccount.com/keys'
try:
    g = requests.post(url, verify=True)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    print err
    sys.exit(1)
print g
```

I get:

```
<Response [403]>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authenticate using OAuth2 to be able to use the service. The `403` error you're receiving is expected because your not authenticating before trying to use the service.

See the following links for some information on authenticating via these methods:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Authenticating to the service may look like the following:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/path/to/service.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
```

Comment: But I don't have a file... File means it's constant isn't it? Shouldn't I get auth for every API call?

Comment: Yep that's correct. In the method I've used above, you would already have a service account setup and `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE` would be the path to the private key that was generated when you created the account.

Comment: Are you looking to use a dedicated service account to make API calls? Or are you looking to use your own account to make the call?

Comment: I have a service account setup from where do i get the Json? Also, What If I need to upload a file to google storage? What needs to change in the code?

Comment: I just want to upload Json file to storage and then process it with BigQuery. It's a process that will run from cronjob.

Comment: The private key in JSON format should be created when the service account is created. I'm don't quite understand what you mean by uploading it to Google Storage? What service will you be using to run the code? Compute Engine?

Comment: The code will run from EC2 machine on Amazon (at least for the next few month).. it won't stay this way for long.  The code connects to a API - generate a JSON from it then upload it to Google storage and eventually update tables over BigQuery.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to retrieve a JSON key using the Google API? It looks like you could just create a service account with scopes to run BigQuery and then run these commands on your EC2 instance. Also note that the GET API call your using will retrieve the Public Key for the service account, not the Private Key you need to make authenticated calls.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you... I have a API (of my store) I get a Json file of my orders... I want to upload it to google storage and then process the file to big query. The EC2 runs the script that suppose to do all that. Since the script connects to google it needs the auth.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174164/discussion-between-scottmcc-and-jack).